# When creating a foreign key do I also need to include the fields from the linked table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Apologies, this is quite a fundamental part of SQL and I'm sure it's a question that has been asked before, I just can't find an example that relates to mine enough for me to understand it. Almost all the resources I find are things like employee/manager relationships which I think I understand but can't apply to my situation!

I am using MSSQL Server 2008. I am creating a database which has 3 tables. It will be used for a simple web application that allows people to record which cars they have double parked in front of (thus blocking in), so that the owner of the blocked car knows who to contact if they want to move the car.

- Cars - Details about people's cars.
- People - who can own at least one
  car.
- ParkedCars - This is where I'm getting stuck.

See below:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Cars
(
  Pk_Car_Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Manufacturer VARCHAR(55),
  Model VARCHAR(55),
  Colour VARCHAR(50),
  RegistrationNo VARCHAR(10) 
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.People
(
  Pk_People_Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  FirstName     VARCHAR(55),
  LastName    VARCHAR(55),
  Extension INT,
  Fk_Car_Id   INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Cars(Pk_Car_Id)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.ParkedCars 
(
  PK_ParkedCars_Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  FK_Car_Id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Cars(Pk_Car_Id),
  FK_People_Id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.People(Pk_People_Id),
  DateParked datetime
);
```

My question is - when creating the `ParkedCars` table, do I need to reference things like `people.FirstName` or `Cars.RegistrationNo` as a column of their own? Or can I do what I have done above and just create foreign key columns? So the table may look something like this when populated with data:

```
+------------------+-----------+--------------+--------------------+
| PK_ParkedCars_Id | FK_Car_Id | FK_People_Id | DateParked         | 
+------------------+-----------+--------------+--------------------+
| 2                | 1         | 5            | 19/2/2016 08:33:00 | 
+------------------+-----------+--------------+--------------------+
| 3                | 4         | 2            | 19/2/2016 08:48:33 | 
+------------------+-----------+--------------+--------------------+
```

Then I can just select the relevant fields from each table and display the results.

I did try a similar method but every time I tried to insert any data, it got stuck because one of the keys was set to null while inserting that particular row. It didn't allow any further data to be inserted into any table.

Please can someone explain the best way to tackle this kind of thing?

Thanks

Comment: A fk without columns specified => referenced table's primary key. With columns specified you can chose any key in referenced table, both pk and unique key.

Comment: Your schema seems to be almost correct (at least ParkedCars part; I'm not talking about Fk_Car_Id key in People table - this creates some logical conflict). What kind of code (insert statements) do not work for you?

Comment: INSERT INTO dbo.ParkedCars VALUES(3, 2, NULL) gives an error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__ParkedCa__A05ED27107F6335A'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ParkedCars'. If I add a value where I have NULL, it works

Comment: Always specify fields list with insert statement - `insert into dbo.parkedcars(fk_car_id, fk_people_id, dateparked) values(...)` - currently you are just attempting to insert primary key (PK_ParkedCars_Id ) and of course this doesn't succeed.

Comment: What if a person owns two cars? (I do...)

Comment: If people have two cars then they would have 2 records in the cars table linked to their people record? I think! I would hope that works, but guess they would then need two records in the people table. How do you get around this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments and whatnot else looks like you have to redesign your schema somewhat.

First, don't use `FK_Car_ID` in `People table`, but use `FK_People_ID` in `Car` table. This solves problem for someone having multiple cars; opposite situation (car has multiple owners) is unlikely. Well, if you need to specify all possible users of said car, then you have to create 'junk' table (`People_Car_Relation`), linking to both car and people.

Second, you don't have to use `FK_people_ID` in `Parked_Cars` table at all - it is enough to link to `Car` only.

Third, create primary key fields as `identity(1,1)` - this way they fill themselves and you don't have to calculate ID values beforehand.

Then remember - never use insert statement without specified fields list. Currently you are attempting to insert record with specific (duplicate) primary key value, which doesn't succeed.

Always use next syntax for inserts:

```
insert into dbo.parkedcars(fk_car_id, fk_people_id, dateparked) values(...)
```

this way you can be sure that your SQL code does what you intend it to do.

Comment: Thanks Arvo. I have been doing some testing using your method and it works much better, especially when inserting data. For some reason I assumed that everything needed to link to everything kind of in a circle but it seems as long as there is a path to follow, data can be retrieved. Is this correct? The hard part for me is working out which tables need to be linked to which and in which order.

Comment: You should avoid duplicate paths, cycles and other data duplication - this creates often problems. What about link order - start from table, containing main events or items, for which you need additional info. Like in your case - your main events are car parkings, thereby you should start with `parked_cars`. From this table, you can join to `Car` and from `Car` already to its owner - `People`. You can alaways start from simpler query, look at results, join another table, look at results and so on. This way you notice immediately, when something breaks.

Comment: Thanks Arvo. I have marked yours as the answer because it has solved all the problems I currently have with the database & helped me understand how to use keys.

Answer (score 2):

As @Arvo stated, your schema looks good..
(Maybe with minor tweaks, for example, I'm not sure you need the FK_People_Id field in the "parked_cars" table since the "People" table relates to the  "Cars" table anyways).

If you're having trouble with NULL keys, I would suggest looking into "OUTER JOINS", if you're not familiar with the subject already, and see if that helps you.

Also, make sure that when you write SELECT statement that contain the "parked_cars" table, you'll probably want to call the "cars" table TWICE!!!

Here's an example, (hope it'll work):

```
SELECT parked.ParkedCars_id, c1.RegistrationNo, p1.FirstName, p1.LastName,
       parked.Fk_Car_id, c2.RegistrationNo, p2.FirstName, p2.LastName
FROM dbo.ParkedCars AS parked
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Cars c1
 ON parked.ParkedCars_Id = c1.Pk_Car_Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.People p1
 ON c1.Pk_Car_Id = p1.Fk_Car_Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Cars c2
 ON parked.Fk_Car_Id = c2.Pk_Car_Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.People p2
 ON c2.Pk_Car_Id = p2.Fk_Car_Id;
```

Comment: That works (sort of) for selecting data but what about inserting? By the way something like this works as expected for selecting the relevant data. `SELECT * FROM dbo.People as p
join dbo.Cars as c on p.Fk_Car_Id = c.Pk_Car_Id
where RegistrationNo like 'EK%'`

Comment: What ABOUT inserting data?? What's your use-case? I mean..... where are you running into trouble while inserting? It sounds to me that inserting is considerably easier than selecting. If you take out the unnecessary Fk_People_Id field in the parked_cars table than all you need to do when inserting is specify 2 registration numbers and a date. 

Things might become more complex if you wish to make a single statement and have data inserted into 2 or more tables.

For this, you could just write a T-SQL stored procedure and use that for insertion, or use table triggers, or read up on CASCADING.

Comment: I was going to use ASP.NET scaffolding to manipulate the data. The user would be able to select and  'block in' 2-3 cars at a time then remove the record later in the day (by deleting their records from the grid).  Alternatively it would be removed after 24 hours automatically. So basically i would be inserting to the parkedcars table based on the logged in user's details and the cars/people they select.

Comment: Ok cool, so whenever a new user registers you add them to the People table. When they add a new car to their profile, you add it to the Cars table. And when they block somebody, you add the event to the ParkedCars table. I'm not really familiar with ASP.NET scaffolding, but nonetheless, I'm still not seeing the problem.  :O

Comment: I think it all stemmed from having an extra key that wasn't needed. It all seems to be working properly now. Thank you for your advice ;)